# WatchOS snap to next row on scroll in WKInterfaceTable

Tags: scroll, watchkit, watchos-2, watchos, wkinterfacetable

Apple's own **Activity** app has an interesting feature that I try to re-implement in my own watch app: Each page in the activity app is scrollable and basically has 2 vertical pages. The first page is the circle and the second page shows more information.

But these pages don't normally scroll up and down when using the digital crown - they **snap**. So you can't scroll in between pages. Apple seems to be using a `WKInterfaceTable` with two rows but I don't find any documentation how you can implement the snapping behavior.

How did they do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WKInterfaceTable`'s `- (void)scrollToRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index` to scroll to a specific row. To get feedback from the digital crown directly you'd have to use `WKInterfacePicker`, but that may or may not work in your case.